# Cache of NSFetchedResultsController is invalid. When do I need to refetch a cache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a crash. I guess it is because a cache of NSFetchedResultsController is invalid.

```
Crashed: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x145938b0
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000004
-[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]


- (ManagedRoutePoint *managedPointAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
                             withFetchResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {    
   id objectOrId = [[controller fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

In my programm I add and remove some manageObjects. I want that my cache will be valid (objects not be released).
Do I need to update my cache only when I remove a manageObject?

Comment: are you using ARC in your project? almost looks like a deference of a NULL pointer.

Comment: yes, I'm using ARC

Comment: show how you're creating the FRC, the context is uses, and explain what triggers the changes (tell us about the threads you're using)

Comment: Code of my project was created by old approach (background thread + privateContext). Now I want to rebuild it with performBlock. I'll tell you if crash will remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems when I accesses a managed object from the wrong dispatch queue. I found this when I add

```
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1
```

to my app on the command line via Xcode’s Scheme Editor.